# Why is there a discrepancy between Yulaw's body count and his charges for illegal jumping?

Tags: the-one

In the 2001 film "[*The One*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_One_(2001_film))", former MVA officer Gabriel Yulaw discovers that by killing his variants throughout the multiverse, each one's essence is divided among the surviving variants, thus making them stronger, faster, and more durable. In theory, the last one will have nearly godlike power.

After he is apprehended, he is charged with 123 counts of jumping universes without permission. Or, as the MVA warden puts it:

> *Gabriel Yulaw, the peoples of the multiverse have found you guilty... of 123 counts of first-degree murder, and 123 counts of unauthorized travel to parallel universes by use of illegal quantum tunneling.*

Surely, though the first one was an accident while on an *authorized mission* to apprehend someone else. So even if you consider that to be murder, it should only be 12***2*** counts of unauthorized travel.

**How do we explain the discrepancy between Yulaw's counts of murder and his counts of illegal jumping?**

Comment: At least one of the universes does not have a Jet Li clone in a funny wig. Maybe he did a jump, found no-one to kill and then did another jump

Comment: The film didn't receive a novelisation, which is odd for this type of movie. The script is also unpublished at this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You've not taken into account the jump that results in his capture.**

Yulaw's first jump (From his own Universe #1 to Universe #2) is legally authorised but ends with his first murder being committed, albeit arguably through self-defence. He then decides to illegally jump to Universe #3, kills his second victim, jumps, and finally ends up in Universe #124, having killed 123 versions of himself and made 122 illegal jumps.

He then ***attempts to jumps to Universe #125 but gets [re-routed by MVA Agents back to Universe #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGaAZ.png)***, resulting in one final count of illegal jumping, bringing the totals to 123 bodies, 123 illegal jumps.

---

That all being said, you might also want to note that not every jump would necessarily result in a successful murder. There are, according to Funsch, universes where there's no duplicate Law.

> "In this universe, you're you. **In another, you don't exist**".

It's possible that Yulaw made *multiple other jumps* that the MVA aren't aware of because he didn't leave a body behind him and that they have no direct evidence that he did a jump in some instances, other than that a duplicate was recently murdered, providing the MVA with only *circumstantial* evidence of his guilt (e.g. that he both murdered someone and illegally jumped)

Comment: Actually, I think it's Funsch who gave Gabe Law the speech about him not existing in a universe. Gonna try to find a clip of that.

Comment: Found one, with Vietnamese subtitles and English voices: https://youtu.be/bZZ2I4fcRoo?t=87

Comment: @Clockwork - Good catch. Either way, it's someone that you would expect to have knowledge of these sorts of things.

Comment: I'll buy that. I didn't consider the aborted jump because he didn't actually do it, but that makes sense.